# Subversion: "svn update" loses CSS data

Tags: css, linux, svn

Recently, I've noticed strange behavior by Subversion. Occasionally, and seemingly randomly, the "svn up" command will wreak havoc on my CSS files. 99% of the time it works fine, but when it goes bad, it's pretty damn terrible.

Instead of noting a conflict as it should, Subversion appears to be trashing all incoming conflict lines and reporting a successful merge. This results in massively inconvenient manual merges because the incoming changes effectively disappear unless they're manually placed back into the file.

I would have believed this was a case of user error, but I just watched it happen. We have two designers that frequently work on the same CSS files, but both are familiar and proficient with conflict resolution.

As near as can figure, this happens when both designers have a large number of changes to check in and one beats the other to the punch. Is it possible that this is somehow confusing SVN's merging algorithm?

Any experience or helpful anecdotes dealing with this type of behavior from SVN are welcome.

Comment: Files with lots of repetitive content often confuse diff/merge algorithms, because there are several different ways to choose the "equal" lines.

Comment: I hadn't considered that. My brain was thinking of different CSS classes/definitions, but I forgot to consider that several lines within those classes would be duplicate styles. Are you aware of any ways around this?

Comment: `svn update` allows you to specify a `--diff-cmd` option to supply an alternate merge program. So you need to find a merge program that's better at dealing with these files. At a previous job I had this problem when doing diffs, not merges, and the only diff program I found that worked well was kdiff3. But it's a GUI app, I don't know if there's a CLI API.

Comment: I didn't know that was an option. I guess I'll start looking for a new diff/merge program.

If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can find a diff/merge program that's better at detecting the minimal changes in files of this structure, use the `-diff-cmd` option to `svn update` to invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

It may be tedious but you can check the changes in the CSS file by using

```
svn diff -r 100:101 filename/url
```

for example and stepping back from your HEAD revision. This should show what changes were made , at what revision and by whom. It sounds like a merging issue I've had before but unfortunately I found myself resolving it by looking at previous revisions and merging them manually too.